# Count occurrences of distinct values with multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, union

I have 3 tables in a database that have similar values and the same table structure. I am trying to get the number of occurrences of each `value` by unique `user`.

**DB Structure**
[View on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/005153/1)

#### TABLE_1

```
user | value | id
```

#### TABLE_2

```
user | value | id
```

#### TABLE_3

```
user | value | id
```

I can run the following MySQL command to retrieve the desired results on 1 table at a time.

```
SELECT value,COUNT(*) as count FROM TABLE_1 GROUP BY value ORDER BY count DESC;
```

I need to run this command across the three tables at once in order to retrieve the unique occurrences of "value" among a list of "users" that contains numerous duplicates.

Comment: do you want to remove the duplicate counts?

Comment: @JohnRuddell I do. The `UNION` command accomplishes that. @sgeddes answer works great.

Comment: how large are your tables?

Comment: @JohnRuddell Large: TABLE_1 = 2,951,132 rows, TABLE_2 = 2,093,633 rows, TABLE_3 = 6,261,184 rows - The solution is working in TABLE_1 and TABLE_2 but when adding TABLE_3 the php return states `mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`

Comment: that is because the query is failing... union isn't a super fast solution.. meaning it is timing out. returning a false aka boolean

Comment: @JohnRuddell is there a better solution for a larger dataset?

Comment: I think you should change the data structure some.. or at least add another table that stores all unique users for you to join on... I can post an answer about that if you would like. just let me know

Comment: @johnruddell I would appreciate that, if you have the time.  I can re-ask the question to make it more defined if needed.  As the answer that was given using `UNION` works on smaller datasets.  It actually works great even with adding `LIMIT 1,1000000` to the end of each `SELECT` query.  BUT It is not accurate across the entire dataset.

Comment: first thing try selecting out just the user from each table. and union them.. something like `SELECT DISTINCT user FROM table1 UNION SELECT DISTINCT USER FROM table2.. etc`

Comment: @JohnRuddell Here it is in [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/005153/18) I don't think I have done what you have asked, though.

Comment: no what I mean is on your database.. see if that query times out or not.

Comment: @JohnRuddell using this command:`SELECT DISTINCT user FROM TABLE_1 UNION SELECT DISTINCT user FROM TABLE_2 UNION SELECT DISTINCT user FROM TABLE_3;` it returned 17,965 rows in 5.8375 sec

Comment: so you have 18k distinct users then?

Comment: What I would do from here is create a table that stores each user. then JOIN by user from the other tables... that would probably be 3 times faster

Comment: @JohnRuddell I have 18,830 to be exact. Not sure why the two numbers are different.

Comment: @JohnRuddell So I exported the query and made a table `USERS` but am unsure of how to use it with `JOIN` relative to  `SELECT value, COUNT(*) as count  
FROM (  
  SELECT user, value, id  
  FROM TABLE_1  
  UNION  
  SELECT user, value, id  
  FROM TABLE_2  
  UNION  
  SELECT user, value, id  
  FROM TABLE_3 ) t  
GROUP BY value  
ORDER BY count DESC;`

Comment: Hang on a sec I'm writing it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your comments, since you want to remove duplicates, use `UNION` to combine the data from the tables together:

```
SELECT value, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM (
  SELECT user, value, id
  FROM TABLE_1
  UNION
  SELECT user, value, id
  FROM TABLE_2
  UNION
  SELECT user, value, id
  FROM TABLE_3 ) t
GROUP BY value 
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

- [Updated Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/005153/9)

Comment: I need the output to be distinct.  Using "UNION ALL" outputs all occurrences of said value, not unique.  For example, the correct output would be 'car = 8' as it is duplicated in Table_1 and Table_2.

Comment: @joshclemence -- then use `UNION` instead.  It will remove the duplicates.

Comment: Perfect! For some reason it wasn't working for me previously.  I was getting a unique identifier error.  Thanks.

Comment: Just to make totally clear something that is implicit in the above comments: ["A `DISTINCT` union can be produced explicitly by using `UNION DISTINCT` or implicitly by using `UNION` with no following `DISTINCT` or `ALL` keyword."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use UNION -

```
SELECT value, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM (
    SELECT user, value, id
    FROM TABLE_1
    UNION
    SELECT user, value, id
    FROM TABLE_2
    UNION
    SELECT user, value, id
    FROM TABLE_3 ) tables
GROUP BY value 
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Output -

```
+-------+-----+
|car    |8    |
|boat   |4    |
|truck  |3    |
|house  |2    |
|skates |1    |
|bike   |1    |
+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

to go along with the comments this is what I would recommend you do.

#### setup:

```
CREATE TABLE members (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    username varchar(255),
);

INSERT INTO members (username)
SELECT DISTINCT user FROM table1
UNION SELECT DISTINCT user FROM table2
UNION SELECT DISTINCT user FROM table3;
```

#### altering:

```
ALTER table1
    ADD COLUMN user_id INT(10)
    ADD INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`);

ALTER table2
    ADD COLUMN user_id INT(10)
    ADD INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`);

ALTER table3
    ADD COLUMN user_id INT(10)
    ADD INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`);
```

#### updating:

```
UPDATE table1 t,
JOIN members m ON m.username = t.username
    SET t.user_id = m.id;

UPDATE table2 t,
JOIN members m ON m.username = t.username
    SET t.user_id = m.id;

UPDATE table3 t,
JOIN members m ON m.username = t.username
    SET t.user_id = m.id;
```

#### removing non normalized data

```
ALTER table1
    DROP user;

ALTER table2
    DROP user;

ALTER table3
    DROP user;
```

now you can also set up foreign key contstraints on the user_id and id columns if you would like.

but to query a total count you can just join the tables.. make sure you add an index on each of the id fields so it will join properly.

```
SELECT your_stuff
FROM members m
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.user_id = m.id
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.user_id = m.id
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.user_id = m.id
```

Comment: I made it all the way to Updating in your example above and now I am getting a MYSQL #1104 Error: `#1104 - The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay` Any ideas on how to approach? - - - It may help to know that in table1,2,3 there is already a primary key set and indexed in addition to the column you suggested altering to index.

Comment: you may have to `SET SESSION max_join_size = #` but what i'm suggesting is that in those three tables user_id is a foreign key to the primary key in members. that way joining will be much more simplistic and faster

Comment: I have set `user_id` as the foreign key for `table1,2,3` relative to the primary key `id` within table `members` ------ But I am still getting the #1104 error when Updating.  And when I prepose `SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1` to the query, nothing happens. - I am not finding a good way to run a check to make sure foreign keys are set correctly.

Comment: I ran `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` and there are no Foreign Key's under Constraint_Type although I have ran `ALTER TABLE table1
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_PerMember
FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
REFERENCES members (id);`